# Prestashop Customized Product

Tags: colors, customization, prestashop, product

I'm developing a site at work and we need a custom product system.

We are trying to allow the user to customize their product (for example; a skipping rope). We want them to have the option to change the colour of multiple parts (Handles, Rope) and upload a custom logo to be displayed on the handles.

I already know how to do the custom logo through Prestashop's customization menu but is there any way of doing the two colour option without buying a £100~ module?

Thanks!

Edit: Figured out you can add multiple color attributes to the product and then add combinations with their own image.

Comment: If you're gonna try and do it youself, you'll send way moer than 100 quid in time. If there is a satisfactory module available, I recommend buying it.

Comment: I've managed to figure this out. You can just add more than one colour attribute to the product and then add combinations, if you give the combination a different image it works pretty well.

Comment: StackOverflow prefers that you post  an answer to your own question and then click "accept" rather than edit the word "Solved" into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out you can add multiple colour attributes to the product and then add combinations with their own image.